# performant way of generateSecureRandom()

Tags: java, java-security

The method `generateSecureRandom()` is called very often by different threads and I use this token also for database ID generation.

Should I put the fields `random` and `encoder` on class level to make it more efficient (thread-local?) ?

If put `random` or `encoder` on class level, will the access to `SecureRandom` be locked for other threads while one thread is using it? I do not want to create a pool of SecureRandom instances but use Thread-Local.

```
public final RandomGenerator{

  public static String generateSecureRandom() {

      // field will be created on each method call
      final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

      // field will be created on each method call
      final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding();


      byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
      random.nextBytes(buffer);
      return encoder.encodeToString(buffer);
   }
}
```

Should I put the fields `random` and `encoder` on method level or on class level?

Comment: [`SecureRandom` objects are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/SecureRandom.html)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I know, and **this is not the question**. I think, `SecureRandom` it **locked** to ensure that it can be used by multiple threads. So it is not really efficient when thousands of threads accessing it..that's the reason why `UUID.randomUUID()` is also not efficient, because it uses single instance of `SecureRandom` for any thread and it will do the lock behind. Which Is what I want to avoid by using `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: Have you tested with a `private final static ThreadLocal<SecureRandom> random`? It should improve performance. Also the encoder is thread safe so you don't need to create one each time (not sure if that's significant or not performance wise).

Comment: @asylias Interesting. What do you think is better: to create `SecureRandom` within the method call or put it on class level (even with ThreadLocal)? What do you recommend for very high (simultanously) method access rates of `generateSecureRandom()`?

Comment: @assylias Thanks. I will accept this as an answer if you make the answer :) but you know `SecureRandom` is by default thread safe..however a lock is made if other threads accessing it..

Comment: The only valid answer is that you should test various options and see which one works best. My guess is that creating a new SecureRandom is quite intensive so reusing them via a ThreadLocal is probably more efficient. If you run the test (for example with jmh) you can post your results as an answer ;-)

Comment: @assylias yes, right. Creating a new SecureRandom is quite expensive..

Comment: @assylias I created the answer with your help. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a comparison of various approaches https://github.com/apache/openwhisk/issues/2747#issuecomment-331089914

Answer (score 6):

I think, using `ThreadLocal` and putting `random` and `encoder` on class level is better than using it without `TreadLocal`.

Besides, putting `random` and `encoder` on method level is not recommended because creating `new SecureRandom` on each method call is quite expensive..

```
public final class SecureRandomString {

    private SecureRandomString() {
    }

    // don't use SecureRandom without ThreadLocal, 
    // because it will block other threads while one thread is using it
//  private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    // use thread local for high throughput
    private static final ThreadLocal<SecureRandom> random = new ThreadLocal<>();

    // the encoder does not need a ThreadLocal 
    // because it is thread safe and no lock is required by accessing it
    private static final Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding();

    public static String generate() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[20];
        random.get().nextBytes(buffer);
        return encoder.encodeToString(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am in doubt with the `ThreadLocal`-approach because it can bring the famous **thread local memory leak**. Any suggestion how to avoid this?

Comment: You will have one SecureRandom object per thread as long as the threads are alive. When one of the threads is terminated, the object will be eligible for garbage collection. So a "leak" can only happen if you keep threads running when they should have died.